# How to find tags inside tags using Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to know how to find a tag inside another tag.

The data source is like this:

```
<ul class="DB_su a1" style="display: none;">
  <li><a href="link">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="link2">text2</a></li>
  <li><a href="link3">text3</a></li>
  <li><a href="link4">text4</a></li>
  <li><a href="link5">text5</a></li>
  <li><a href="link6">text6</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="DB_su a2" style="display: none;">
  <li><a href="link">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="link2">text2</a></li>
  <li><a href="link3">text3</a></li>
  <li><a href="link4">text4</a></li>
  <li><a href="link5">text5</a></li>
  <li><a href="link6">text6</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="DB_su a3" style="display: none;">
  <li><a href="link">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="link2">text2</a></li>
  <li><a href="link3">text3</a></li>
  <li><a href="link4">text4</a></li>
  <li><a href="link5">text5</a></li>
  <li><a href="link6">text6</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

This is the Python code that I made by referring to HTML sources.

```
for flink in range(11):
   count = str(flink + 1)
   ss = soup.find('ul', class_='DB_su a' + count)
   dd = ss.findAllNext('a')
   print(dd)
```

This resulted in more results than the desired data. Not only the data inside the tag was collected, but all the next tags were collected.

I want to get this `href` tag:

```
[link, link2, link3, link4, link5, link6]
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I am using BeautifulSoup and we also use selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "for flink in range(11)" try to add some like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """
<ul class="DB_su a1" style="display: none;">
  <li><a href="link">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="link2">text2</a></li>
  <li><a href="link3">text3</a></li>
  <li><a href="link4">text4</a></li>
  <li><a href="link5">text5</a></li>
  <li><a href="link6">text6</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="DB_su a2" style="display: none;">
  <li><a href="link">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="link2">text2</a></li>
  <li><a href="link3">text3</a></li>
  <li><a href="link4">text4</a></li>
  <li><a href="link5">text5</a></li>
  <li><a href="link6">text6</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="DB_su a3" style="display: none;">
  <li><a href="link">text</a></li>
  <li><a href="link2">text2</a></li>
  <li><a href="link3">text3</a></li>
  <li><a href="link4">text4</a></li>
  <li><a href="link5">text5</a></li>
  <li><a href="link6">text6</a></li>
</ul>
       """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for n in soup.find_all('ul', attrs={'class': 'DB_su a3'}):    
   for x in n.find_all('a'): 
    print (x.get('href'))
```

result:

```
link
link2
link3
link4
link5
link6
```

Comment: Thank pros ! Do you know how to collect a3 and a2 and a1 all at once?

Comment: @GyoungmanChoi in case just you want <ul> with class name start with DB_su a ...use some like this : attrs={'class': re.compile(r'DB_su a')}):

Comment: As I used the method you told me, I got the data I wanted. Thank you.